# Adding data to state array in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add new data to a state array on a project, however, every time I update or close the app to see if the changes are still there, they arent.

```
addChild = dataUser => {
const { children, initialValues } = this.state;
const { name, lastname, birthdate, gender, specialCares, details } = dataUser;
const dataToSend = { name, lastname, birthdate, gender, specialCares };

const isFieldsComplete = this.checkIfFieldsComplete(dataToSend);
if (details.trim() !== '') dataToSend.details = details.trim();

if (isFieldsComplete) {
  if (initialValues) children[initialValues.index] = dataUser;
  else children.push(dataUser); // <- This is where I push the new data.

  this.setState({ isEditingChildren: false, initialValues: null });
} else {
  this.showAlert(
    'Complete fields', 'Please complete fields.'
  );
}
```

So, can you guys help me to tackle this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mutate state directly by doing `children.push(dataUser);`

If you're not using the hooks implementation of setting state, then you need to use `setState` and do something like the following:

```
this.setState({
   children: [...this.state.children, datauser]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you shouldn't mutate your state, instead, when you need to update the state based on your previous state you should use the function approach of the `this.setState` method, which goes like this:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  children: [
     ...prevState.children,//<-- Paste the previous state
     dataUser//<-- Add your new data to the children's array
  ]
}));
```

Because `this.setState` is asynchronous, this will also make sure that your `state.children` is what you're expecting it to be at the moment of making the update.